# How to load CSV file to object in angualrjs?

Tags: csv, angularjs

In angularjs I created some `service` that loads JSON object:

```
// used to load table from json file instead ajax
myModule.factory('Items', ['$http', function($http){
    var Url   = "src/utils/some.json";
    var Items = $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
     return response.data;
  });
  return Items;
}]);
```

And in controller I can call it like:

```
Items.then(function(data){
  $scope.items = data;
});
```

As You can see I load `some.json` file.

What should be flow to do the same with `CSV` file?

in my case  `$scope.items` is a list of objects.

Does someone know how to get CSV data by using `$http.get` or other way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to parse the CSV file into an array. You can see this question for some alternatives: [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Then you'll end up with something like this:

```
myModule.factory('Items', ['$http', function($http){
  var Url   = "src/utils/some.csv";
  var Items = $http.get(Url).then(function(response){
     return csvParser(response.data);
  });
  return Items;
}]);
```