# Return and display JSON data after uploading excel/csv file from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, csv, file-upload

I had a hard time trying to display/return the JSON data after uploading my csv/excel file from [AngularFileUploader](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

I have followed this [example](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/tree/master/examples/simple), the upload part is working. But I don't know how to display the data from the file in JSON after upload. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right place to do that:

```
    uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        // "response" should be the "echo $json" from PHP
    };
```

Comment: do you mind give me more details? i understand the this method is able to display the data. But for example, I upload a csv file and I want a json data sheet print out. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You are asking about upload a file and get response about upload status, this is completely different by parsing the content of a file. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933711/how-to-load-csv-file-to-object-in-angualrjs