# How to convert the loaded csv data to JSon object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, csv

I have to load a CSV file using upload and then use the contents of this file(converted to JSON) to call a REST Interface using $http post request. This request wants input data in JSON format.

Please suggest me how to do the same. I have tried the following as of now. I am able to load the file and read its content. How to create the JSON onject from the same. Code as follows:

'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [])

```
.controller('fupController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.data = '';
    $scope.toJSON = '';

    $scope.add = function(){
        console.log("Add called");
        var csvFile = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
            reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e){
            var data = e.target.result;
            console.log("File Name: ", document.getElementById('file').files[0].name);

            $scope.data = e.target.result;

            // Trying to convert to JSON object
            $scope.toJSON = angular.toJson($scope.data);

            console.log("Json Data: ", $scope.toJSON);

            // --> $http POST request with the JSON onject as input data
        }

       reader.readAsText(csvFile);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Select File to upload</label>
                  <div ng-controller="fupController">
                      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".csv"/>
                      <input type="button" ng-click="add()" value="Upload" />
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load CSV file to object in angualrjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933711/how-to-load-csv-file-to-object-in-angualrjs)

Comment: You can probably just split the text from the file on the commas and then stringify the resulting array.